# Help ID a trapped in time comic

Tags: story-identification, comics, time-travel

I'm trying to find an old comic I once read.

Details:The story involves a group of scientists that are tossed back in time to the 1800's. They have no way of getting back. I think they tried to make a binary computer (like in back to the future)

They realize that they are not the only ones thrown back, so they reach out to the others scattered by organizing a revival (or something) that is hosted by Mick Jagger with music by the Rolling Stones etc. This allows them to find many other people like them.

They are also, oddly enough, attacked several times by cyborgs flying ships that look like dirigibles. It seems all of the science they introduce before society is ready causes mass overpopulation, pollution, and ecological collapse...so this new time line send back people/assassins to stop them from making a horrible world like theirs.

I have tried multiple google searched about trapped in time, lost in time, etc, and get nothing, but it was a multi-edition comic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Brave Old World](http://www.comicvine.com/brave-old-world/4050-6427/), written by William Messner-Loebs and published by Vertigo.

Synopsis of Book 1 [The Century Turns; Abort, Retry, Reboot?](http://www.comicvine.com/brave-old-world-1-book-1-the-century-turns-abort-r/4000-46259/)

> When the computer glitch everyone feared instead causes time itself to flip back to the year 1900, it's up to a band of elite computer programmers to reinvent the technology of the digital age in a barely industrial America. Their plan is to hack their way back into the 21st century by creating a bug-free computer age, but other issues, such as survival, take precedence when aliens from an alternate, dystopian year 2000 (a timeline created by the team's activities in 1900) travel back in time with orders to kill.

First occurrence of a hostile time traveler in Book 1
[image: First occurrence of a hostile time traveler in Book 1]

Invitation to Mick Jagger's assembly in Book 4
[image]

Comment: This is it. Thanks so much.